# Unable to see created game in AoE2 in Windows 7

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I am trying to play in Local Lan multiplayer between a Laptop, which is connected through Wifi and a desktop PC which is connected through an ethernet cable to the same router. both PCs can ping each other, and I can play other games with no issues. But with Age of Empires 2 no matter who creates a multiplayer game the other person cant "see" the game in the list of available games.

One interesting thing to note is that, when playing *Starcraft: Broodwar* I can create a game but only in UDP, not in IPX. ( Could that be the reason?  If so, is it possible to install IPX protocol in Windows 7).

For now I am playing using Gameranger which works but it sucks due to network latency when we are *in the same network :(*

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I think that is notoriously hard. Last time I tried, I ran into the same problem. In the olden days I used to play it using Hamachi, however: maybe you can give that a try.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks for your response. I cracked it though. you can check what I did on the response. Now it works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally cracked it. For anyone having this issue, the problem is that Windows 7 does not support natively the IPX protocol anymore.

So to overcome this, you can download this app : http://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/

This will **automagically** convert your network packets to IPX using UDP tunneling. I tested it and it works like charm! Now the game works fine and we can play through Lan with no issues and most importantly **no lag at all**.

So, to quickly sum up, this is what I did to make it work:

1. Deactivate the firewall in your *Domestic network* in the Windows Network setting.
2. Download IPx wrapper and unzip all the files in the same folder as the executable of the game. For instance, we play **The Conquerors** expansion so I right click on the properties of the shorcut and then on *Open file location*.

Thats where you should place all the files. Do this for every machine that will join the game. Once the files are copied there are two .reg files you should execute, depending if you are in either 32 or 64 bit version of Windows. Execute it before going to the next step.

3. Open the game in one machine and create a game using *IPX* protocol. **NOT** using TCP/IP.
4. Other users are now able to see the game even if they are in Windows 7.
5. Enjoy an awesome game.

Comment: The original AoE 2 is able to use standard TCP/IP, why not simply use this? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352120/how-can-we-get-a-lan-party-going-for-age-of-empires-2-kings-or-conquerors

Comment: @Crovaxon Thanks for the reply. I cant modify my router config to enable Upnp, as my ISP resets the router config remotely every 12 hours. Also, I have not interest in online gaming. But when I do I can use Gameranger and dont have to mess wiht any configs.

Comment: I believe UPNP is not even necessary to enable in the router, you are playing in LAN after all, no need to get out into the internet. But I cannot verify this, don't have old AoE 2 on hand. If you are fine with no firewall while playing in LAN, just disable it on both machines and create a lobby. The other should normally see the game. Keep in mind to choose Local TCP/IP as the connection type in game for both machines. It's how I played with my little brother years ago. But if you are happy with your solution that is fine as well.